# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method vision#startImageLabelDetector on channel google_mlkit_image_labeler)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-mlkit

final List image = await imageLabeler.processImage(inputImage); // <---Error Exception

I am using an android.

I have seen a person with the same exact issue, but they were running on the web, and it is not implemented to run on the web. I am using an android, so there should be no problems.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

```
import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_image_labeling/google_mlkit_image_labeling.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_commons/google_mlkit_commons.dart';

final List image = await imageLabeler.processImage(inputImage);
```

the example shown above was taken from a youtube video, word for word, so there should be zero problems.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giVk7yGUkas&t=244s&ab_channel=LearnwithJahangirJadi

EDIT
i tried closing editor/ doing a flutter clean/ and closing my app, I encountered another proble

```
Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.)
```

adding these to the pubspec.yaml files causes this error

```
 google_ml_kit:
 google_mlkit_image_labeling:
 google_mlkit_commons:
```

removing them fixes the error.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you stopped your app and runned it again from the start ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens to me, try to run these steps:

```
flutter clean
```

```
flutter pub get
```

close your code editor, your app/emulator, and try again.